# What is the best method to predict the water consumption of EACH customer for the next month?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, unevenly-spaced-time-series

Say we have a dataset that has the following attributes:

- customer_id: There are a total of 1000 customers, each of them with a unique customer_id
- observation_date: The date on which we last observed the amount of water a certain customer has consumed (yyyy/mm/dd)
- amount_consumed: The amount of water a customer had consumed on the observation date (since the last observation date)

Now, as I said, there are a total of 1000 customers, all with observations taken at different intervals. The intervals are between 30~45 days and mostly unequal for each customer. The data spans over 2 years , and we have about 19~24 observation for each customer (19~24 observations per customer_id).

Here's a sample data for one customer:

[image]

The customers live in a residential area of a large city, with particularly hot summers and normal temperature conditions in the other seasons.

From what I understand, we need to use Time Series Forecasting methods on this data. If I want to forecast the amount of water consumed by every customer in the next month, do I have to train a different Time Series model for every single user? (e.g. train 1000 different Time Series models, each belonging to a certain customer_id)

Also what algorithm would you recommend for this type of thing (ML, etc.)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: These are good questions but collectively they are overwhelming.  Please think about which one is most important to get answered first and edit your post to focus on it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I edited the question and made it more focused. Would appreciate it if you opened it back up.

Comment: If water users live in high rise condominiums in a large city their water usage may not be seasonal. If water users live in suburbia with landscaping that needs to be irrigated at some times of the year, but at other times, then their water usage in the 'next' month will be difficult to predict without seasonal data. // Can you describe your situation more precisely than vaguely mentioning 'time series'?

Comment: The water users live in a large city. We're taking a look at a mostly residential area of the city. The observation for each user is made in 30~45 day intervals, and for a large part of them, this interval varies greatly. For instance, one observation is made at 2018/03/11 and the another is made at 2018/04/16 and so on.

Comment: And those observations is the total cumulative usage since last measurement?

Comment: This looks like a *hierarchcal time series*. Search this site, or https://robjhyndman.com/files/3-Hierarchical.pdf

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen The observations are the amount of water consumed since the last observation date. e.g. at 2018/03/11, customer_1 has consumed 150 liters of water, at 2018/04/16, customer_1 has consumed 100 liters of water and so on.

Comment: So from what I see (and I come from a purely ML background), with hierarchical time series, I need to train a time series model for each customer_id? @kjetilbhalvorsen

Comment: Did you read the link? There are multiple ways to do hierarchical time series, I'm not sure what is best. Another way is to start with the aggregate series, and use that to constrain the individual predictions to have the right sum.